# Formulas for max number of intersection points on a plane, and in space

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

The maximum number of intersection points of $n$ lines on a plane is given by $n\choose2$.  How do we derive this formula?  I see that we can $n\choose2$ $= \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$, where the $rhs$ is just the sum of $1+2+...+n$.
$\phantom{}$

and also, how do we get that the maximum number of vertices formed in $R^3$ by $n$ planes is given by $n\choose3$.  I see that we can only form a vertex in $R^3$ with $3$ planes, but not sure how to derive the formula.

Thanks

Comment: Try induction.  Suppose there are $n$ lines with $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ intersections.  Pick a point lying on only one of them and create an $n+1$-st line choosing a slope in such a way that the new line creates $n+1$ new intersections.

Answer (score 1):

Two lines can intersect each other once or not at all. An intersection point is formed by a pair of two lines. We get the maximum intersection points by counting all possible pairs of two lines. There are ${n \choose 2}$ such pairs and since they can only form one point each it's the maximum of intersection points.
The same argument works for the planes aswell.

I hope this might help you

Comment: Recommend adding a proof or argument that the maximum is achievable for lines and planes.